# POSTMAN - How to fetch data using POST method instead of GET?

Tags: api-testing, postman

This is the url on which i'm sending a GET request to access data - [reqres.in/api/users?page=2](https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2)

The data i'm getting in response is somewhat like this

```
(id - 1, name - john, job - QA ; id - 2, name - sam, job - Web Dev)
```

Now, I want to access the same data

`(id - 1, name - john, job - QA ; id - 2, name - sam, job - Web Dev)`
using the POST method on this URL.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just send your POST request with parameters - not as URL query.

Instead of using

```
GET /service/function?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

use

```
POST /service/function { param1 : value1, param2 : value2 }
```

2. Another option - if you use Apache server.
   You may send POST request without ending slash in url - and server will redirect you (300) and transform to GET request.

Answer (score 0):

At the left of the URL input you will find the dropdown where you can select the HTTP method to use. You can choose POST.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the same data using POST method in POSTMAN, you will need to follow the steps mentioned below:

1. In the address bar, enter the URL reqres.in/api/users.
2. Change the request method to POST.
3. In the Body section, select the "x-www-form-urlencoded" option.
4. Add the parameter "page" and value "2" in the key-value pair.
5. Send the request by clicking on the "Send" button.

This will send a POST request to the URL and you will receive the same data as a response.

Note: This will work if the API support POST requests for this functionality.